# How to replace an item in an IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda

Currently, to replace an item I'm using the following code:

```
var oldItem = myList.Single(x => x.Id == newItem.Id);
var pos = myList.ToList().IndexOf(oldItem);

myList.Remove(oldItem);

myList.ToList().Insert(pos, newItem);
```

So, I created an extension to do the same as above but using lambda expression, and I came up with this:

```
public static ICollection<T> Replace<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, T oldValue, T newValue) where T : class
{
    if (list == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list));

    return list.Select(x => list.ToList().IndexOf(oldValue) != -1 ? newValue : x).ToList();
}
```

So I can use it as follows:

```
var oldItem = myList.Single(x => x.Id == newItem.Id);
myList = myList.Replace(oldItem, newItem);
```

However, it's not working. What am I missing?

Comment: `IEnumerable` isn't really designed for replacing things and by design it can't be deterministic whether you could/should iterate over them multiple times.

Comment: I assume that `Id` is unique, consider a `Dictionary` where the key is `Id` and the value is `item`.

Comment: How many times do you need to check if `oldValue` is in `list`, not to mention converting a potentially open-ended enumeration into a `List<T>` once for each item in the enumeration?

Comment: If you can use IList<T> instead of IEnumerable<T>, you can replace items easily with first obtaining an index and then setting new item if index >= 0. This way only first item would get replaced.

Comment: Not sure I understand the logic: If `oldValue` is anywhere in `list`, return an enumeration entirely of `newValue`, otherwise return `list` as-is? Were you intending something more like `.Select(x => x == oldValue ? newValue : x)`? Not to mention you really want `yield return`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I think that falls under "it's not working".

Comment: Replace doesn't work when there are multiple children.  The replace replaces one item at a time and when there is multiples the links to other children must be kept so the replace ends up with same results as start.  What usually works is following for(int i = oldItem.Count(); i >= 0; i--){ oldItem[i] = newItem;}

Comment: @Rawling That's a surprisingly common error, I find.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Then I guess we should make a canonical question so that we can close questions with that problem as a duplicate of it.

Comment: @Servy All we need is a canonical answer.

Comment: Do you really need it to work on `IEnumerable` wouldn't `IList` do?

Comment: Suggestion: Iterate the `myList`  collection to only find the to-delete items  - capture (reference to) those in a 2nd collection. Then iterate this 2nd collection and remove those items from `myList`. Straight forward, easy to test/debug, avoids mid-iteration collection changes.

Answer (score 5):

While you can't replace the item in the materialized collection itself, you *can* replace the item that is *yielded from a different* `IEnumerable<T>` at a certain position.

All you have to do is use the `Select` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` to map to the new item when the `Id` property matches, and use the new `IEnumerable<T>` instance, like so:

```cs
// Assuming newItem is already defined, has the value you want to yield
// and T is the type of newItem
IEnumerable<T> newEnumerable = myList.Select(i => 
    i.Id == newItem.Id ? newItem : i
);
```

Then, when you iterate through the `newEnumerable`, when the item in the old list has an `Id` equal to `newItem.Id`, it will yield `newItem`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a hard time doing this with `IEnumerable` as that interface is designed for iterating.  However, you can get things working with `IList`

```
    public static IList<T> Replace<T>(IList<T> list, T oldValue, T newValue) where T : class
    {
        var pos = list.IndexOf(oldValue);

        list.Remove(oldValue);
        list.Insert(pos, newValue);
        return list;
    }
```

With test code of

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<Item> myList = new List<Item>() { new Item { Id = "123" }, new Item { Id = "abc" }, new Item { Id = "XYZ" } };

        var newItem = new Item { Id = "abc" };
        var oldItem = myList.Single(x => x.Id == newItem.Id);

        myList = Replace(myList, oldItem, newItem);
    }
```

For an obvious definition of `Item`

```
class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public readonly Guid Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

Since your sample code shows the use of `ToList()`, maybe creating a new collection (rather than modifying an existing one) is fine.  If that's the case, you would write your `Replace()` method as follows

```
    public static ICollection<T> Replace<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, T oldValue, T newValue) where T : class
    {
        var l = list.ToList();
        var pos = l.IndexOf(oldValue);

        l.Remove(oldValue);
        l.Insert(pos, newValue);
        return l;
    }
```

Comment: This will not actually _replace_ the item but rather remove the old and add the new at the end.

Comment: @Magnus When it doesn't just crash because the input isn't necessarily a collection to begin with.

Comment: @Servy True, makes no sense to take in a IEnumerable and then force it to be ICollection. Should take in ICollection from the start in that case.

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable` is for traversing a generic data structure. Think about it as read-only access. In fact, making modifications to the `IEnumerable` while enumerating it is a big NO NO. Your original solution is fine, except for the last line. Just do Remove and Insert.